Extremely slow wifi between Ubuntu 24.04 LTS laptop and Deco M5 mesh access points
I have an Ubuntu 24.04 LTS laptop (dual boot with Windows 11) which connects via its mt7921e wireless card to 99% of wifi SSIDs at full normal speed, but connected to my Deco M5 mesh access points absolutely crawls, 5 second ping times to the router, less than 100Kb/s download.
If I connect directly to the router's SSID (not via the mesh) I get full speed again. If I connect the Windows install on the same laptop using the same wifi card to the same Deco I also get full speed, as does every other device connected to them. It is just a problem between the Ubuntu install and the Deco mesh.
I've set the QoS setting on the Deco app to the full speed of the line, and forced the laptop to use the fastest and least contested channel (via nmcli d wifi) for the Deco, I've set the connection to use DHCP and also set a manual address/dns/route etc, neither makes any difference. I've tried reinjecting the driver, no dice. Power management for the interface is turned off. I hear talk of downgrading the kernel but that seems like a sensible option if all wifi was slow, where this is just with one particular device (or rather a mesh of them). It is a problem with any of the 3 mesh access points too.
I am stumped so if anyone has an idea to try I'm all ears.
The bot suggests my question is unclear so here is a short version:
What might cause a slow connection between an Ubuntu laptop and a TPlink Deco M5 mesh when all other devices connect at high speed and the laptop connects at high speed to any other network?

Usually, the bot is accurate, but here, I believe your question is clear. +1

I just moved to Ubuntu 24.04 yesterday and was having the same issue with the internet going up and down as well as being slow as heck. I tried multiple things but what fixed it for me was a combo of two things.

Go into your terminal and enter this command:

sudo nano /etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/default-wifi-powersave-on.conf
Change wifi.powersave to 2
Press CTRL+X to exit, it'll ask if you want to save.
Press Y and Enter.

I followed this YouTube video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Rc7lZV_xvTU

The last step of the YouTube was to reboot.
